# C++ Have to put input in twice

Tags: c++, visual-studio, input

Im using Visual Studio Professional 2013.
When ever running simple code like:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int _tmain()
{
int choice;
double fahr, cel;

    cout << "Please choose 1 for Fahrenheit, or 2 for Celsius conversion: ";
    if (cin >> choice) {
        while (cin >> choice){
            if (choice == 1)
            {
                cout << "Enter Fahrenheit degrees to be converted: "; 
                cin >> fahr;
                cel = (fahr - 32.0) / 1.8;
                cout << fahr << " degrees Fahrenheit is " << cel << " degrees Celsius" << endl;
                cout << "Please type a character followed by Enter, to end the program";
                int stop; cin >> stop;
                return 0;
            }
            else if (choice == 2){
                cout << "Enter Celsius degrees to be converted: ";
                cin >> cel;
                fahr = 9.0 / 5.0 * cel + 32.0;
                cout << cel << " degrees Celcius is " << fahr << " degrees Fahrenheit" << endl;
                cout << "Please type a character followed by Enter, to end the program";
                int stop; cin >> stop;
                return 0;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Not a valid option" << endl
                    << "Please run program again...";
                int stop; cin >> stop;
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

return 0;
```

}

The output of the program is this:

```
Please choose 1 for Fahrenheit, or 2 for Celsius conversion: 1
1
Enter Fahrenheit degrees to be converted: 32
32 degrees Fahrenheit is 0 degrees Celsius
```

I have to input my choice twice, for the rest of the program to run.
in the example above, I have to put the temperature I want converted, twice for it to convert it once. the first time I put it in, it just moves to a new line.

any clue as to why?

**edited to include code and output**

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show an example session with all output and input? Any maybe a more complete program (preferably a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/))?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because of `if (cin >> choice) { while (cin >> choice){`.

Comment: Additionally you can remove the `while`, because you return after one loop execution anyway. (If there is no other intention for this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (cin >> choice) {
    while (cin >> choice){
```

This asks for input twice.

Get rid of the `if` and just do the `while`.

Comment: Thank you! I dont know why I had that in there. I hadnt even really noticed it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (cin >> choice) {
    while (cin >> choice){
```

to

```
while (cin >> choice){ // you already got the input, don't need to read it twice.
```